# /home/vhosts/ or /var/www/

Tags: linux, web-server, storage, home-directory

Some web servers I've come across use /home to store the site files:

```
/home/vhosts/www.example.com/
```

Others use /var like:

```
/var/www/www.example.com/
```

What's more clean and "Linuxy"?  Should we all be using `/usr/local/www/`?

Possible sources: http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/linuxdir.html

Comment: Shared hosting providers tend to chroot users to their own home directory with their own www (and other services) directories.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Chapter 3 of the FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM) (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard) 2.3, data for services provided by a server should go under `/srv`, but leaves the organization under it pretty much in charge of each specific system.

I would recommend `/srv/www/<domain>` or if the server is providing multiple services per domain something like `/srv/<domain>/<service>` (service being `www`, `ftp`, `svn`, etc).

Comment: So if a server provides MySQ servicesL, then the data should go in /srv/sql/dbname? I have never seen any Linux distribution putting data into /srv. And moving the default location for service data (eg /var/lib on Debian) to /srv is just a royal pain.

Comment: Well [FHS has a rationale](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLIBVARIABLESTATEINFORMATION) for `/var/lib` too. Just think that in case of `/srv/` you are serving files directly from there, while with MySQL you are really reading data from a socket. Also notice that FHS is a suggestion and work in progress so each distribution nas some space to maneuver.

Comment: @Wim: Distributions should *not* put data into `/srv`: "... no program should rely on a specific subdirectory structure of /srv existing or data necessarily being stored in /srv."

Answer (score 7):

[Red Hat](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s1-filesystem-fhs.html) and [Debian](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#s-web-appl) use */var/www*. If I was accessing an unfamiliar server, that is the first place I would look for a web server's document root.

Comment: +1 for sticking with defacto standards/convention.

Comment: Also +1 for pointing a good place to start.