# Where to put www directory on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, directory

I'm a bit scared to ask this because I got so many negative votes for simply asking a question last time, but here goes;

Where in the Linux (Ubuntu) directory structure is it 'normal' to put public and private website files.

Say I have a server and I want directories;

```
mysite1.co.uk/
mysite1.co.uk/www/
mysite2.co.uk
mysite2.co.uk/www/
```

where would they normally be put?

Update: I'm using Nginx (not Apache).

Comment: This is probably because this is a too basic question which indicates that you didn't read any documentation, HOWTO or just googled.

Comment: I have seen `/var/www/fqdn` and `/srv/www/fqdn` on various systems.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/267183/home-vhosts-or-var-www/267184#267184

Comment: @mailq I did Google. For example; http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/linuxdir.html and http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-file-system-structure/ and http://www.debianadmin.com/linux-directory-structure-overview.html and one other I can't remember.

Comment: Have a +1 for having the balls to ask a fair question on what can be intimidating site! But like others have said, it doesn't matter where you place the files, it can boil down to personal preference.

Comment: @Coops. Thanks! Nice to know it's not just me that finds it somewhat intimidating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under `/var/www`. But this is not a convention you have t follow. You can put them wherever you want, as long as Apache has access to it.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'm using Nginx not Apache. Does that change your recommendation?

Comment: no. Doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
/var/vhosts/domain.name/html
/var/vhosts/domain.name/logs
```

but `/var/vhosts` is a symlink to `/srv/vhosts` in my case.  I had my cake and ate it.