# Standard Location for Git Repository on Ubuntu 11

Tags: ubuntu, git, repository

What is the proper location for storing a central git repository on an Ubuntu 11.04 server?

I read [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/267183/home-vhosts-or-var-www/267184#267184) and there appears to be conflicting information.  This is related to www, but the idea is the same.

I currently have the repository located in `/var/lib/git.repo`.  I read the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLIBVARIABLESTATEINFORMATION) and it looks like I should have chosen `/srv/git.repo` or `/var/git.repo`, which is the source of the conflicting information in that previous post.

Answer (score 1):

I usually stick them under /srv, but in this case, it doesn't matter a whole lot.

Comment: Why would it not matter?  Isn't the point of this so that anyone who admins your server can find it?  If everyone put their repositories where they wanted to, would that not be an issue?  Why have any standard at all if that is the case?

Comment: Since you already did some reseach on your own a couldn't find a good standard that may just indicate there is none.  While following standards certainly helps when working with other sysadmins, sometimes you just have to make local decisions and then document them

Answer (score 0):

"The Proper Location" is location, there **all local users** (ssh:// in mind)  can **read and write** repo files according to their rights.

Nothing more, nothing less